# How to Get ReactRouter V4 to Return Status Code 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

With ReactRouter V4, I can use `<Switch>` to get the last route to run a `<NotFound>` component, but what I really want is a redirect to the server that then generates a true 404 so search engines know not to index the 404 page itself as valid. I've got my code below. I find examples of how to do this when using Server Side Rendering, but not when using a pure client based app only.

```
export default () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/speakers" component={Speakers}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route   component={NotFound}  />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
};

const NotFound = () => (
    <Status code={404}>
        <div>
            <h1>Sorry, can’t find that.</h1>
        </div>
    </Status>
);

const Status = ({ code, children }) => (
    <Route render={({ staticContext }) => {
        console.log('staticContextx');
        if (staticContext) {
            console.log('staticContext');
            staticContext.status = code;
        }

        return children
    }}/>
);
```

EDIT: ADDED TRY THAT WORKS BUT IT FEELS VERY UGLY.

I added to my node server a check for the redirect to /NotFound, then put a `location.href` in the `<NotFound>` component.  This feels wrong, gives some extra page flashing and I'm not sure how search engines will handle.  Open to better ideas.

Routes.js

```
const Status = ({code, children}) => (
    <Route render={({staticContext}) => {
        if (staticContext) {
            staticContext.status = code;
        } else {
            window.location.href="/NotFound";
        }

        return children
    }}/>
);
```

Node Server:

```
import express from 'express';

import React from "react";
import renderer from './renderer';
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public', {
}));

console.log(path.resolve('public','index.html'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/speakers') {
        console.log('URL...:' + req.url);
        console.log('speakers URL (no renderer):' + req.url);
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('public','index.html'));
    }
    else if (req.url === '/login'){
        //res.redirect('/index.html');
        console.log('login URL (renderer)');
        res.send(renderer(req));
    }
    else if (req.url === '/NotFound') {
        res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        res.status(404).end("Not found, 404 status returned");
    }
    else {
        console.log('other URL (no renderer)');
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('public','index.html'));
    }
});

app.listen(3010, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3010 svcc');
});
```

Comment: i am afraid you may not be able to do it in client side. because you already have a valid status 200 for ```index``` .html where you are mimicking routing behavior. client-side routing does not actually change the url. its only changing the hash value, which can be anything.

Comment: @hannadrehman is this what folks do in general with React? It seems that this would be a big fail if everyone does this.

Comment: How does state management help for urls that don’t exist and getting 404s out?